# Constraints are not the same?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, swift4.2

I aligned both views to the bottom safe area on two different ViewControllers, but if i change **BOTH** BottomConstraints constants to -100 one view is going up and one is going down even though they aligned the same way. I want the constraints to act like the first ViewController, because all other ViewControllers have worked like that.

First ViewController:

[image: First ViewController]

Second ViewController:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is this

> First item  = Second item * multiplier + constant

if you reversed the order of First , Second same **-100** will act differently which currently happens with you , so ensure whether your custom view is always in place of First / Second in both constraints

[image]

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail. I haven't understood it. What do I have to do?

Comment: click both constraints and check whether your custom view is the first / second in both of them

Comment: oh thank you it works now. But why does it happen when they're reversed and how can i prevent it so it does that automatically ?